# PickUp/Apply Paragraph Formatting in PowerPoint 2007

Tags: vba, format, powerpoint, apply

In PowerPoint 2007, PickUp/Apply does not capture some paragraph formatting, such as bullet formatting, when used programmatically (VBA).  Adding the PickUp and Apply buttons to the Quick Access Toolbar (QAT) and trying this manually confirms this.

However, if you triple-click on a bulleted paragraph and select PickUp from the QAT, then go to another bullet in another shape, triple-click it, then select Apply from the QAT, the bullet formatting is successfully applied.

Programmatically, my approach was then to select all paragraphs in the source shape and use PickUp, then select all paragraphs in the target shape and use Apply.  That didn't work.  For example, I tried several variations on the following:

```
'oSource.TextFrame.TextRange.Select
oSource.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.Select
oSource.PickUp

'oTarget.TextFrame.TextRange.Select
oTarget.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.Select
oTarget.Apply
```

So, how can I make PopwerPowin 2007 apply the paragraph formatting in one shape to another, without copying each Paragraph property individually, either using PickUp/Apply or some other technique (in VBA, of course)?

Comment: Definitely open to some crazy code if that's what makes this work.

I have developed some code of my own to work around this problem, but it's not quite perfect.  Not sure how to post code in a comment, though.

Comment: So post it as an answer?

Perhaps you can do something with CommandBars.ExecuteMso